# Ambiguous method call println char array and String (instead of Object)

Tags: java, generics, overloading, wildcard

```
public class Task03<K> {
        public <T> T foo() {
            try {
                return (T) new Integer(42);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                return (T) new Integer(43);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Task03<?> v = new Task03<>();
            System.out.println(v.foo());
        }
}
```

I have a compile error on line `System.out.println(v.foo());`
Ambiguous method call: Both println(char[]) and println(String) matches

It's not clear for me why java is trying to use this 2 methods instead of `println(Object)` or `println(int)`

How can we understand this java compiler behavior?

Thank you

Comment: `println(Integer)` doesn't exist. `println(String)` and `println(char[])` are more specific than `println(Object)`.

Comment: Even if `println(Integer)` did exist, the compiler wouldn't consider it any more specifically than the `String` and `char[]` overloads. There's nothing in the method signature that implies an `Integer` will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java selects the most specifically-applicable method. Because `<T>` is determined at the call site, any of the `PrintStream.println` methods that take a reference-typed parameter could be selected.

From [JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

Anything that you can pass to `println(char[])` or `println(String)` can also be passed to `println(Object)`, therefore the former methods are more specific than the latter. As such, these will be selected in preference to `println(Object)`.

However, some things that can be passed to `println(char[])` cannot be passed to `println(String)`, therefore neither of those is more specific than the other, hence the ambiguous method call.

Comment: Everything that I can pass to println(int) or println(double) can also be passed to println(Object). Why char[] or String methods are more specific that int or double?

Comment: Potential methods are matched in 3 passes, becoming less strict on each pass, and only proceeding to the next pass if no methods are found on the current pass. `char[]`, `String` and `Object` are matched on the first pass; `int` and `double` would be matched on the second pass, which allows matching with unboxing (except matching never gets this far).